# Resizing UIImageViewFrame to match size of image

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiimageview

I have the following view setup:

```
private func setupViews() {
    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.clipsToBounds = true
    containerView.backgroundColor = .gray

    view.addSubview(containerView)

    containerView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 100.0)
    containerView.center = view.center

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "one")

    imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 100.0))
    containerView.addSubview(imageView)

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let imageView = gesture.view as? UIImageView else {
        return
    }

    let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)

    let newX = imageView.center.x + translation.x
    let newY = imageView.center.y + translation.y

    imageView.center = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
    gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
}
```

It consists of a container view of width: 300.0 and height: 100.0, and a UIImageView of the same dimensions inserted as a subview. A pan gesture is also added.

When the code is run the layout is as expected. A larger image that doesn't fit the frame will scale using the content mode specified, which also works as expected. However I am only able to pan the image within the frame width: 300.0 and height: 100.0. How can I resize the image view frame so it matches that of the resized photo?

Comment: do you mean to have a larger image inside the containerView which to be like a scrollable image within size 300 * 100 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is saying: *"Show the image at the same size as the container view"*.

What you want to do is set the `imageView` **frame** to the same size as the image.

Take a look at this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupViews()
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        
        containerView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 100.0)
        containerView.center = view.center
        
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "one") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!")
        }
        imageView.image = img
        
        // set the imageView frame to the same size as the image
        imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height))
        containerView.addSubview(imageView)
        
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    @objc func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let imageView = gesture.view as? UIImageView else {
            return
        }
        
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        
        let newX = imageView.center.x + translation.x
        let newY = imageView.center.y + translation.y
        
        imageView.center = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }
    
}
```